# Nested foreach and check if update/insert query or delete query is in order?

Tags: php, mysql, nested

Ok here's a function with a nested foreach and i want to check if a key value pair needs to be deleted or updated/inserted. But this one doesn't work, maybe you can see where i go wrong

```
function insertUserShoppingMetaData($params) {
        global $wpdb;
        $shopping_meta_table = 'wp_shopping_metavalues';
        $wp_user_id = $params['wp_user_id'];
        $checkKeyValues = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_shopping_key FROM $shopping_meta_table WHERE wp_user_id = '$wp_user_id'");
        //print_r($checkKeyValues);
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {

            foreach($checkKeyValues as $check){
                //UPDATE OF INSERT
                if (($check->meta_shopping_key == $key) AND ($key != "wp_user_id")) {
                    if (is_array($val)) {
                        $val = json_encode($val);
                    }
                    $shopping_meta_values = array(
                        'wp_user_id' => $wp_user_id,
                        'meta_shopping_key' => $key,
                        'meta_shopping_value' => $val
                    );
                    $shopping_meta_where = array('meta_shopping_key' => $key, 'wp_user_id' => $wp_user_id);

                    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $shopping_meta_table WHERE meta_shopping_key = '" . $key . "' AND wp_user_id = '$wp_user_id'");
                    if (count($result) > 0) {//KEY ALREADY EXISTS FOR USER
                        $return = $wpdb->update($shopping_meta_table, array('meta_shopping_key' => $key, 'meta_shopping_value' => $val), $shopping_meta_where) . '<br/>';
                    } else {//KEY IS NEW
                        $return = $wpdb->insert($shopping_meta_table, $shopping_meta_values) . '<br/>';
                    }
                }//.end $key
                else {
                     //KEY IS NOT SELECTED ANYMORE SO DELETE key value pair row
                    $qdel = $wpdb->delete($shopping_meta_table,array('wp_user_id'=>$id));
                    $return = 'Deleted: '.$qdel;
                }//.end else {
            }//.end foreach checkKeyValue

        }//.end each
        echo 'Test return: ' . $return;
    }
```

Comment: You can use mysql INSERT IGNORE statement. So that it will not insert duplicate entries into the database. Set the field which you want to be unique to be unique in database.  Please check this link for more info http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Comment: @KrishnadasPC hmm i don't want to ignore an insert. In this case i have to deal with registered user who can edit there preference before a certain date. So i like to update a key pair, insert a new  pair or delete a key value pair if the user deselects the option